# Downloading files using HTML does not save until program exits

Tags: c#, windows, file, download, httpclient

I have been working on this for a week.  I have done a lot of searching and a lot of tests for different methods.

When I use HttpClient to download a file, no errors are generated but the files do not show up in the folder until after the program exits.  I have a synchronous method (before someone asks - no I cannot change it to asynchronous) that calls an asynchronous method to download language files for my Tesseract OCR (I test with language == "eng"):

```
if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
Task.Run(async () => await HelperMethods.LoadLanguage(folderName, language));
Task.Run(async () => await HelperMethods.LoadLanguage(folderName, "osd"));
```

And here is the method that is being awaited:

```
public static async Task LoadLanguage(string folderName, string language)
{
    string dest = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(folderName, $"{language}.traineddata"));
    if (!File.Exists(dest))
    {
        // Now we know that we need network - start it up if it isn't already.
        if (httpClient == null)
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri($"https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/{language}.traineddata");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
            await fs.FlushAsync();
            fs.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I added the Flush and Close as part of the testing, but it did not make a difference.

This is supposed to download the language files and allow the next lines to perform an OCR using those languages.  The files are downloaded and are written to the folder (only show up) after the program exits.

If I run the program a second time, it works - because it does not need to download new files.

How do I get this to download the files and save them immediately so the files can be used in subsequent operations?

I also tried this method:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
var sendTask = httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var response = sendTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var httpStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

using (var fileStream = File.Create(dest))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpStream))
    {
        httpStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        fileStream.Flush();
    }
}
```

No difference.  And quite a few other methods of working with the stream.
This is .NET framework 4.8 (not able to update to .NET6).

Comment: Can you create a [mcve], so that others can try to reproduce the issue on their systems? For example, a simple console application that does nothing but downloading a single file which reliably reproduces this issue would go a long way. Hint: Make sure it's really as short as possible, or people here won't bother trying to reproduce it.

Comment: don't you have to await [`Task.Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-7.0#system-threading-tasks-task-run(system-action))? Like `var task1 = Task.Run(async () => await HelperMethods.LoadLanguage(folderName, language)); task1.wait()`

Comment: Based on the reference in your post, consider swapping the `windows` tag for `.net-4.8`.

Comment: Suspicious part that it actually downlads files consistently - that should not happen. You may want to explain why you expect the code to actually return data synchronously as it looks like you have some sort of misunderstanding of threading/tasks/asynchronous code, but it is unclear what that misunderstanding is.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov : I will be doing more research into properly using async methods (not just for this project).  I obviously misunderstand how **await** works as I thought this would wait for the result to be returned - and it's not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post states

> I have a synchronous method [...] that calls an asynchronous method to download language files

If the caller is synchronous anyway, why not make the downloader synchronous, too?

```
public void LoadLanguage(string folderName, string language)
{
    Enabled = false;
    try
    {            
        Uri uri = new Uri($"https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/{language}.traineddata");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response =
                client
                .GetAsync(uri)
                .GetAwaiter()
                .GetResult())
            {
                var bytes =
                    response
                    .Content
                    .ReadAsByteArrayAsync()
                    .GetAwaiter()
                    .GetResult();
                File.WriteAllBytes(
                    Path.Combine(
                        folderName,
                        $"{language}.traineddata"), 
                    bytes
                );
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

I tested this and it seems to work [[clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/tesseract-ocr-load-language-4-8.git)]. Does this get you any closer?

Comment: Thank you.  After all of my research into using HttpClient and reading that it needed to do everything asynchronously, this does fix the problem.  I did change the "using" line for the HttpClient, though to avoid the issues with socket exhaustion as this method can be called dozens of times from the main program using a series of different language files.